# I am facing segmentation fault(code dumped)

Tags: c

I wrote this simple code as a beginner while practicing 'C' Language. The aim here is to measure the perimeter and area of the inputted values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double width;
    double height;
    double perimeter;
    double area;

    printf("Enter the Width of Rectangle:");
    scanf("%f", width);

    printf("Enter the height of the Rectangle:");
    scanf("%f", height);

    perimeter = 2*(width+height);

    area = width*height;

    printf("Perimeter of the Rectangle=%f\n", perimeter);
    printf("Area of the Rectangle=%f\n", area);
    printf("Hence the problem is solved");

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile code. It gives me this specific error every time.

```
D:\Mandeep\prog pro\Learning C\Learning_1.c||In function 'main':|

D:\Mandeep\prog pro\Learning C\Learning_1.c|12|warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double *' [-Wformat=]|

D:\Mandeep\prog pro\Learning C\Learning_1.c|15|warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]|

D:\Mandeep\prog pro\Learning C\Learning_1.c|15|warning: 'height' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
```

Later, when I run the program it shows me **segmentation error** after inputting the "width of the rectangle".

Comment: Please help me solve this error. So, I can make myself sure that I don't repeat such a mistake again and again.  Please do try to explain about segmentation fault in laymen terms.

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to `scanf`, for example `scanf("%lf", &width)`. There's a lot of good resources on the internet on pointers in C.

Comment: Read carefully the specifications of `scanf`, and what arguments it expects.  Indeed, the compiler warning tells you exactly what is wrong.  If your code triggers compiler warnings, you shouldn't expect it to work correctly unless you have completely understood what the warning means and why it is not a problem for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `scanf` is incorrect. `scanf` expects to get a pointer:

```
scanf("%lf", &height);
```

Comment: When I tried your answer. It gave me results without a segmentation fault. But the result was inappropriate

Comment: You have to do the same for width